# How to plot an Observed and Simulated timeseries as lines and points in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have timeseries of 4 simulated variables, with its 4 observed variables (observed variables have less data than simulated variables) as attached in the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sumgi6pqmjx70dl/nutrients2.csv?dl=0

> I used the following code, The data is stored in "data 2" object

```
data2 <- read.table("C:/Users/Downloads/nutrients2.csv", header=T, sep=",")

library(lubridate)
data2$Date <- dmy(data2$Date)

library(reshape2)
data2 <- melt(data2, id=c("Date","Type"))

seg2 <- ggplot(data = data2, aes(x = Date, y = value, group = Type, colour = Type)) +
        geom_line() +
        facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free") 
seg2
```

This give the plot (all variables in line)
[Plot obtained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5rzx.png)

I need the observed data in points instead of interrupted lines, like this example
[Plot desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZ8UG.jpg)

> How to get a plot like this in ggplot, (simulated variables in line and observed variables in points or dots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to subset your dataset for `geom_line` and `geom_point` in order to use only `sim` and `obs` data respectively.

Then, if you pass `shape = Type` in your `aes`, you can remove dots for `sim` data in your legend by using `scale_shape_manual`:

(NB: I used `melt` function from `data.table` package because I found it more efficient for big dataset than the `melt` function `reshape2`)

```r
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)

library(data.table)
dt.m <- melt(setDT(df),measure = list(c("Nitrate","Ammonium","DIP","Chla")), value.name = "Values", variable.name = "Element")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt.m, aes(x = Date, y = Values, group = Type, color = Type, shape = Type))+
  geom_line(data = subset(dt.m, Type == "sim"))+
  geom_point(data = subset(dt.m, Type == "obs"))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,NA))+
  facet_wrap(~Element, scales = "free")
```

[image]